# Reading lifecycle status of other activities in other applications

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

I'm trying to develop an application that detects abnormal behaviors. So, one of the things it should be able to do is reading the lifecycle status of the other apps ex. Google Play went on pause.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly spoken: Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: isn't there any way around it?